# How to politely express a wish for a gift

Tags: family, birthdays

Background: I have found an item online that I wish I had. Although technically I could afford it, currently I have other expenses so I couldn't really justify that purchase.  I have a birthday soon.

How could I express that wish politely to my family, without appearing rude or demanding? I don't want to make them buy more expensive gift than they would do otherwise.

Comment: Whom are you hoping will be buying this gift?

Comment: Family.........

Comment: To clarify, I don't want make anyone buy anything as much as just give an idea.

Comment: Where are you located? What is your cultural context?

Comment: To add to @Hamlet's request, your culture may determine the proper solution, so it's helpful to include the information. For example, in one place it might be common to have a "wishlist" of items you want that you share with friends and family but in others, that may be inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the size of your family, and your culture, you could tell a family member that what you really want is something that you're saving up for, and then suggest that multiple people pool their resources to get you this one present, together.

If that is too direct, then I would suggest instead just mentioning once or twice that you're going to set aside some money to start saving up for this thing, since you are really excited about it.  That should be enough to give the hint without coming across as pushy or greedy.